# PHP preg_replace remove specific parts from string

Tags: php, regex

im having problems with understanding regex in PHP. I have img src:

```
src="http://example.com/javascript:gallery('/info/2005/image.jpg',383,550)"
```

and need to build from it this:

```
src="http://example.com/info/2005/image.jpg"
```

How it it possible to cut first and last part from string to obtain clear link without javascript part?

Right now im using this regex:

```
$cont = 'src="http://example.com/javascript:gallery('/info/2005/image.jpg',383,550)"'

    $cont = preg_replace("/(src=\")(.*)(\/info)/","$1http://example.com$3", $cont);
```

and output is:

```
src="http://example.com/info/2005/image.jpg',383,550)"
```

Comment: `(src=\")(.*)(\/info[^']*)[^"]*` will work with the string you have.

Comment: It works, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```php
preg_replace("/src=\"\K.*(\/info[^']*)'[^\"]*/", 'http://example.com$1', $cont)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/hEBAZF/1).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  src=                     'src='
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \"                       '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \K                       match reset operator
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    info                     'info'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^']*                    any character except: ''' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  '                        '\''
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^\"]*                   any character except: '\"' (0 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
```

Comment: It works also, thanks for this precise explanation :)

Comment: @PiciuU Glad to hear, please kindly accept the answer by clicking `✓` on the left.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative solution, you might also capture the `src="http://example.com` part by matching the protocol in group 1, so you can use it in the replacement.

```
(src="https?://[^/]+)/[^']*'(/info[^']*)'[^"]*
```

**Explanation**

- `(src="https?://[^/]+)/` Capture **group 1**, match `src="http`, optional s, `://` and till the first `/`
- `[^']*'` Match any char except `'`, then match `'`
- `(/info[^']*)` Capture **group 2**, match `/info` followed by any char except `'`
- `'[^"]*` Match the `'` followed by matching any char except `"`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xpqiMh/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/8d1aA)

```
$cont = 'src="http://example.com/javascript:gallery(\'/info/2005/image.jpg\',383,550)"';
$cont = preg_replace("~(src=\"https?://[^/]+)/[^']*'(/info[^']*)'[^\"]*~", '$1$2', $cont);
echo $cont;
```

Output

```
src="http://example.com/info/2005/image.jpg"
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me an alternative solution :) Finally, I understand a little more about how regex works